# PHP MySQL Login Example Error

Tags: php, mysql

I am quite confused with my php mysql login issue right now. Here is my code.

Please don't suggest me to use mysqli and PDO for now because I am newbie and currently knows only how to use mysql functions in php. I will fix that later. so just please take a look at the code and tell me what is wrong with the authentication code.

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $username=addslashes($_POST['username']);
    $password=addslashes($_POST['password']);

    //connect to database
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","","") or die();
    $db=mysql_select_db("dashboard") or die();

    //execute query
    $query ="SELECT username, password from `login` where username=$username";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    if($username=='username' && $password=='password') {
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
        header("Location:dashboard.php");
    } else {
        echo "You got credentials wrong";
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php htmlspecialchars("PHP_SELF"); ?>">

<label>Username :</label><input type="text" name="username"></br>
<label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="password"></br>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"></br>
</form>
```

dashboard.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "Welcome ". $_SESSION['username'];
?>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_destroy();
header("Location:login.php");
?>
```

Error on page was :

> Notice: Undefined index: password in
>   /home/lampstack/apache2/htdocs/dashboard/login.php on line 23

Line 23 Code

```
if($username=='username' && $password=='password')
```

Comment: You haven't told us the problem. You have a couple though.. Including SQL Injection and PHP 5.5 compatibility.

Comment: As Martin says: there are couple of security problems. But at your question: I think instead of `if($username='username' && ...`, you should use the `==` operator.

Comment: Edited the question with error posted in the bottom of the OP. I had trouble formatting sorry about that. I am trying to make simple login page for now, then after that i am going after sql injection and mysqli queries.

Comment: @ryu - could you also point out which line is line 23?

Comment: Error occurs even after using == operator.

Comment: Don't add security as an afterthought! You will forget something.

Comment: same line where comparison operator is used.

Comment: the error appears in login.php, I assume that the 1st piece of code? It clearly states line 23, so if we get the code from that file exactly as it is we can check line 23 to find your error.

Comment: It does appear in login.php for the line that has  if($username=='username' && $password=='password'). But I want to know how to make a check for an $_Post['username'] to match with the mysql username field. I know my code is meant to have mysql injection, but just want to get the basic example running then i can think of security, but getting downvoted and all for the stuff. Atleast i can know where to go ahead with the code, that would to get some confidence :(

Comment: "I want to know how to make a check for an $_Post['username'] to match with the mysql username field" - That's just basic stuff you can find in most tutorials, this isn't really the place for that. As for the down vote, it's probably because your question wasn't very clear from that start. Also, it should be "<?php", not "< ?php", note how it also doesn't give you color codes here ...

Comment: I tried most of the basic tutorials and you can see the messed up code in OP. I wanted to improve but never mind, back to daniweb. :/

Comment: You were asked to provide the code on line 23...

Comment: Check the updated OP.

Comment: (Error and line don't really match, but...) `Undefined index` normally occurs when referencing a variable that isn't present like `$_POST['unset_variable']`. You should test `if(isset($_POST['unset_variable'])) { ... }` first, before referencing the the value.

Comment: Thanks nisbshtr. I made a change in line 23 where i compared $_POST['username'] with $row['username'] and got the example rolling :)

Answer (score 0):

At first stage in your query

```
$query ="SELECT username, password from `login` where username=$username";
```

You should surround your username variables with quote since i supposed this is not an integer field

```
$query ="SELECT username, password from `login` where username='$username'";
```

Then you have an error in your `if` statement and you didn't fetch any result from your query so you should check for fetched row or either `mysql_num_row` being greater than 0

```
$result=mysql_query($query);

if($row = mysql_fecth_array($result))
{
    $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    header("Location:dashboard.php")
}
```

I would point out that your code is high vulnerable to mysql injections

Comment: @ryu you should switch to pdo and use prepared statement to avoid any risk, anyway have a check to `mysql_real_escape_string`